# Unable to return resultant array from jQuery's $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm working on the User role permissions and for that I've created a form like this:

The generated HTML for each checkbox is

```
<div class="checker" id="uniform-department_create">
    <span>
        <input type="checkbox" 
               class="form-control department" 
               id="department_create" 
               name="department_create" 
               value="create">
    </span>
</div>
```

now `onSubmit` I'll be calling a function that would pull the user's permissions.  It looks like this:

```
var designationForm = {

  // All permissions must be added to this Array
  // to manipulate checkboxes
  permissions: Array('department','customer','designation'),

  ...

  get_permissions: function() {
    var allowed = Array();
    $.each(designationForm.permissions, function(index, permission) {
      allowed[permission] = Array();
      $.each($("."+permission),function(input, value) {
        if ($("#uniform-"+$(value).attr('id') + " span").hasClass('checked')) {
          allowed[permission] += "{"+$(value).attr('value')+":"+"true},";
        } else {
          allowed[permission] += "{"+$(value).attr('value')+":"+"false},";
        }
      });
      return allowed[permission];
    });
    // console.log(allowed);
    return allowed;
  },
  ...
}
```

what it does is basically check permissions array and iterate through all permissions if it finds a checkbox's span containing the class "Checked" it adds it to the allowed array.

if I `console` the result then I can see correct return but I'm unable to return the resultant array.

Comment: Sounds like you may be executing the code in an async request -- perhaps using ajax? If that is the case, then you need to return a promise that you can resolve once the logic has finished executing. Unfortunately, there is not enough code posted to see how that is being done.

Comment: nope, I'm not using the ajax, just trying to get the array returned from `get_permissions` function

Comment: Do you mind creating a quick plunkr that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Are you building a json string by hand, with javascript?

Comment: Try using Chrome Developer Tools, put a breakpoint at the beginning of your function, and step through it.  See what happens.  Also, why are you returning `allowed[permission]` from the `$.each` callback?

Comment: What are you getting back from the `return allowed`?  Nothing?  Something else?  "unable to return the array" isn't very clear.

Comment: @GPicazo I tried to create a Plunkr but unable to do it

Comment: @KevinB is there any better way to generate the JSON object itself since it doesn't have the input checkbox fields, rather it is using `span` with class checked applied to it

Comment: @freedomn-m its returning empty array

Comment: Could the issue be that you are returning from inside the outermost .each loop?

Comment: Looks ok to me:  http://jsfiddle.net/fk2x8w9x/1/   I suspect it's how you are referencing the 'empty array' - it appears empty as you've used `array[string]` to set the values rather than `array.push`.  Have a close look at what appears in your console log

Comment: "is there any better way to generate the JSON object" - well there's a related issue...  you want to create *an object*, not a "JSON object" and *then* convert it to JSON.  But that's an aside to the question issue, this isn't codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thankyou all for the help, @freedomn-m you got it right, a silly mistake, forgot to add the console.log on the calling function, thanks again

Comment: @freedomn-m This question would be off-topic on Codereview. Only working code is on-topic on Codereview, and from the looks of the post, this code is broken.

Comment: @EthanBierlein I agree - I was pointing out that the issue was not with creating a "JSON object" and referencing that doesn't help the question because we're looking at the issue not side issues to do with what the code is trying to do. I wasn't advocating that this code be sent to codereview, but asserting that this is not codereview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I console the result then I can see correct return but I'm unable to return the resultant array.

and

> its returning empty array

Copying the code and adding some extra divs/spans into jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/fk2x8w9x/1 and looking at the console output gives:

```
[department: "{create:false},{delete:false},", customer: "{create:true},", designation: Array[0]]
```

ie, an empty array as described, but with the values set as properties of the "array".

This is because:

- An "array" in javascript is just like any other object and can have its own properties etc.
- You can set properties like `obj.val =` but also set properties via indexer, such as `obj["val"] =`

This is what is happening here - properties are being added instead of array "items".

If you change lines:

```
var allowed = Array();
allowed[permission] = Array();
```

to

```
var allowed = {};
allowed[permission] = {};
```

then it may make more sense.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote so that it can be improved?  Given that this was the issue as already confirmed by the OP: "@freedomn-m you got it right"